# How to integrate Firebase into Google Apps Script without using (deprecated) database secret

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-apps-script

For a while ago I was using [**integration of Firebase in Google Apps Script**](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase) as a server side and it was working finely and still working in my old projects.

But today after creating a new Firebase project and a new realtime database then trying to integrate Firebase Project into my [Google Script project](https://script.google.com/) I got [an error](http://prntscr.com/lfv727) and it's not working completely. And I realize that [**Firebase deprecated database secret**](https://prnt.sc/lfv2n7) for new projects.

So, my question now is how to come over this problem? Is there another way to integrate Firebase into Google Script project?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to add the correct OAuth scopes to the manifest file of your Apps Script project, and then pass in an `access_token` parameter (or in the `Authorization` header) instead of the `auth` parameter you currently use.

Based on [Doug's gist here](https://gist.github.com/CodingDoug/44ad12f4836e79ca9fa11ba5af6955f7), the basic steps are:

1. Open the `manifest.json` from the script editor, by clicking <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Show manifest file</kbd>.
2. Add or edit the manifest to have these OAuth scopes:

   ```
   "oauthScopes": [
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
   ]
   ```

   That last scope grants it access to the spreadsheet itself. If you're using another GSuite type (document, slides, form, etc) you'll need the scope that corresponds that to type.
3. Now you can get the OAuth token from within your script and add it to your request:

   ```
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(databaseUrl, {
     method: "PUT",
     headers: {
       "Content-type": "application/json",
       "Authorization": "Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
     },
     payload: JSON.stringify(json)
   });
   Logger.log(response.getContentText());
   ```

A major advantage of this is that your script will now run as an actual user, meaning that you can ensure it can only perform authorized actions through security rules.

Comment: Thank You Frank!. I really appreciate your help.